# Two fields mapping in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

Is it possible to collect and map two fields from form to one property?

**Details:**

I have an array field in my entity:

```
@ORM\Column(name="custom", type="simple_array")
```

where admin can specify (multi choice) custom options for the product - for example:

```
$product->setCustom( array('customText', 'customNumber') );
```

So the user should have two fields in his order form - text and number. Then I want to save them:

```
$order->setCustomOptions(array(
    'customText' => 'Foo',
    'customNumber' => '100',
    ));
```

In `order` entity there is just array field type instead of simple_array.

User can't add new options so the collection field type isn't a good choice in my opinion.
I have also tried to use data transformer but I think it can be applied only to one field.

Tell me if it's not clear. I don't need a complete solution but a hint what to choose.

Comment: What type is "simple_array"? Could you provide custom type definition?

Comment: It's doctrine type: http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#array-types. We can assume that there is just array for simplicity

Comment: I never used it (infact I was not aware of this type) but I suppose that you should use DataTransformer in order to collect some custom data from form and rever it to that base type

Comment: But there is my problem: how to get data from two diffrent fields by DataTransformer? Add DT to whole form instead of adding it to one field?

Comment: Some idea that I have:

- create two fields (single fields) into yor entity that aren't mapped to DB. Don't use data transformer but make a combination of them after binding form and data

- create a symfony2 custom type that will show two fields and use data transformer to revert to your basic type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I created two additional fields in my Entity (like DonCallisto suggested) without mapping to Database and rendered them in the form. Then instead of using DataTransforem, I used a setter with `@ORM\PrePersist` and `@ORM\PreUpdate` to set custom values together.